# Select all CheckBoxes in a particular column in GridView(asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, select, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview which contains 2 coulmns with checkboxes.
I have one header column with checkbox named Approve all and another named as Reject all. 
When I click either of the checkboxes all the child checkboxes present in that gridview get checked but I want only that particular columns checkboxes to be checked. Please help:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function checkAll(objRef) {
    var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;

            if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
                if (objRef.checked) {
                    row.style.backgroundColor = "#c3d9ff";
                    inputList[i].checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "#c3d9ff";
                    }
                    else {
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    }

                    inputList[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="myGridAlternatingItemStyle" Width="98%" Height="500px" AllowPaging="false" ShowFooter="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <FooterStyle CssClass="myGridTextItem" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="myGridTextItem"/>
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="myGridSelectedItemStyle"/>
    <%-- <HeaderStyle CssClass="myGridHeader" />--%>
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="myGridAlternatingItemStyle" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GVFixedHeader" />
    <Columns>
        <!-- I have few Data columns here -->
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" Text="Approve All" TextAlign="Left" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="myGridHeader" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="90px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckApprove" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="RejAll" Text="Reject All " TextAlign="Left"  runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="myGridHeader" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckReject" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>                   
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: This url might help you [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11207/Selecting-multiple-checkboxes-inside-a-GridView-co]

Comment: Why are you using one checkbox for approve all and another for reject all? Wouldn't that work with just one? You'd change the text on checkAll depending on whether it is checked or not. That's just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to do this type of problem that may reduce your time

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll(data) {
        $('[id$=checkAll]').click(function() {
            $("[id$='CheckApprove']").attr('checked', true);
        });     
        $('[id$=RejAll]').click(function() {
            $("[id$='CheckReject']").attr('checked', false);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should use prop-function for this, $(":checkbox").prop("checked", true); http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: This will always check all the child `CheckBoxes`, regardless of the parent `CheckBox` being checked/unchecked.